# Using PHP on Login Form to replace text

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, authentication, mybb

I'm basically working on a Bootstrap website I've made. I connected my Forum (MyBB) so I could log in through my website.
The problem now is that since I'm still getting used to PHP, I'm stuck attempting to replace the Sign in text with the name of the user and also the Sign Up with Logout or Disconnect.

This is so far how it looks:

[image: This is so far how it looks]

And this is what i would like to achieve:

[image: And this is what i would like to achieve]

Also fetching the forum avatar and displaying it on the bar

This is my form:

```
<?php

    if($mybb->user['uid'])
    {
        // If the user if logged in, display a welcoming message.
        echo "<div class='welcome-msg'>Welcome back ".$mybb->user['username']."!<br /></div>";
        echo "<div class='warning'>Log out.";
    }
    else
    {
        // If the user is not logged in, display the login form.
        echo "<form action='forums/member.php' method='post'>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='action' value='do_login' />";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='url' value='../index.php' />";
        echo "<input id='user_username' placeholder='Username' type='text' name='username' maxlength='30' /><br />";
        echo "<input id='user_password' placeholder='Password' type='password' name='password' /><br />";
        echo "<input class='btn btn-warning' style='clear: left; width: 100%; height: 32px; font-size: 13px;' type='submit' name='submit' value='Login' />";
        echo "</form>";
    }

?>
```

I'm not asking for someone to actually make it, obviously. I just need some reference about how I could achieve it. (Ex: Using what type of)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using bootstrap so you would need to modify the code in your navbar/navigation section using the `if($mybb->user['uid'])` if the user is logged in just swap out the links, using an if/else schema. You would be able to pull whatever data for the database you need to display the forum image etc. If you are using these links in your header the same applies, just modify the area where you deal with Sign Up / Sign In.

Comment: Got it, i been doing some CodeAcademy courses to get a bit more use to PHP. Not a great resource but atleast it works, thanks.

Comment: @JasonStrothorn your welcome and just take your time, `www.udemy.com` is an online learning website with video courses, you can also check out `www.packtpublishing.com` for some ebook deals on web development that can help you out too. Udemy has some free courses and Pact has a few free books if I recall. Keep pushing forward and you'll be a master in no time! (: